# How to load Changed language in android using EasySharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, xml, load, sharedpreferences

i am trying to load the changed language by using EasySharedpreferences, im having the problem of how to load the result now of the saved string, here is the code:

```
public void shqipOnclick(View v){
    Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(startMainActivity);
    languageToLoad  = "sq"; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    sharedPreferenceData.putString("Lang",languageToLoad);

}

public void englishOnclick(View v){
    Intent startMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(startMainActivity);
    languageToLoad  = "en"; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    sharedPreferenceData.putString("Lang",languageToLoad);

}
```

Comment: Post whole code of your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `SharedPreferences()` this way:

```
SharedPreferences saherdPreferences =  getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saherdPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("string", key);
editor.apply();
```

To retreive `SharedPreferences()` :

```
 SharedPreferences saherdPreferences = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
 String str = saherdPreferences .getString("string", key);
```